# Do all Ethereum networks return the revert reasons as a "message" field?

Tags: json-rpc, testnets, revert-opcode

I noticed that reverted transactions on Kovan don't include the revert reason. I'm getting the generic "Reverted"/ "VM execution error."

Is Koval special in this regard? I know that Ethereum Mainnet includes the reason in the "message" response of the JSON-RPC call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not all Ethereum networks return the revert reason in the `message` field. Kovan is an exception.

As per the Infura [documentation](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/ratelimits#response):

> On Mainnet, Rinkeby, Ropsten and Goerli, if this call causes the EVM to execute a REVERT operation, an error response of the following form is returned, with the revert reason pre-decoded as a string:
>
> ```
> {
>  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
>  "id": 1,
>  "error": {
>    "code": 3,
>    "message": "execution reverted: Dai/insufficient-balance",
>    "data": "0x08c3..."
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> On Kovan, the actual revert reason is instead returned encoded as part of the data field in the response.
>
> ```
> {
>  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
>  "id": 1,
>  "error": {
>    "code": -32015,
>    "data": "Reverted 0x08c3...",
>    "message": "VM execution error."
>  }
> }
> ```